# How to get information of raster in rasterio similar to gdal?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I would like to print the raster statistics from its header. This can be done in gdal using the commands.

```
gdalinfo dataset.tif
```

or in Python bindings

```
src = gdal.Open('dataset.tif')
info = gdal.Info(src)
print(info)
```

Is there a similar workflow in `rasterio` to print all raster information?

```
import rasterio 

with rasterio.open('dataset.tif') as src:
   # print info
```

I don't want to use numpy to get raster statistics since it would be computationally expensive in large data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import rasterio
f = "C:\GIS\athreebandraster.jpg"
dataset = rasterio.open(f)

meta=dataset.meta
for k,v in meta.items():
    print(k,': ', v)
print("\n")

for band in range(1, meta["count"]+1):
    stats = dataset.statistics(bidx=band, approx=True) #min, max, mean, std
    print(f"Stats for band {band}: ", stats)
dataset.close()
```

Prints:

```
driver :  GTiff
dtype :  uint8
nodata :  None
width :  7000
height :  15700
count :  3
crs :  EPSG:3006
transform :  | 100.00, 0.00, 240000.00|
| 0.00,-100.00, 7675000.00|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|


Stats for band 1:  Statistics(min=0.0, max=254.0, mean=207.26144671202, std=50.968567671799)
Stats for band 2:  Statistics(min=0.0, max=254.0, mean=220.19104648526, std=51.082257094833)
Stats for band 3:  Statistics(min=0.0, max=254.0, mean=214.21241836735, std=58.629669435145)
```

Comment: Hi @BERA, does it compute statistics whenever its called?

Comment: Thank you very mcuh!

Comment: Nice! I dont know, maybe you can find information [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.BufferedDatasetWriter.statistics)